# t-sql Combinations of k values, n positions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

t-sql Combinations of k values, n positions:

```
K Values
'A', 'B'

N Positions -- can be any value

Result if N = 2:
'A', 'A'
'A', 'B'
'B', 'A'
'B', 'B'    

Result if N = 3:
'A', 'A', 'A'
'A', 'A', 'B'
'A', 'B', 'A'
'A', 'B', 'B'
'B', 'A', 'A'
'B', 'A', 'B'
'B', 'B', 'A'
'B', 'B', 'B'
```

I assume will have to do a n - 1 CROSS JOIN's to itself i.e. use dynamic t-sql?

I.e. when N = 2

```
WITH CTEValues(Value) AS (
    SELECT 'A' UNION SELECT 'B'
)
SELECT c1.Value AS A, C2.Value AS B
FROM CTEValues c1
CROSS JOIN CTEValues c2
ORDER BY c1.Value, c2.Value
```

Or 3

```
WITH CTEValues(Value) AS (
    SELECT 'A' UNION SELECT 'B'
)
SELECT c1.Value AS A, C2.Value AS B, C3.Value
FROM CTEValues c1
CROSS JOIN CTEValues c2
CROSS JOIN CTEValues c3
ORDER BY c1.Value, c2.Value, c3.Value
```

Unless there is away to use unpivot then pivot?

Comment: What's the question? How to make it work for arbitrary k and n?

Comment: use `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: output is clear.input is not clear.what is table design and wht value are store there ?

Comment: You can assume k is fixed always 2, N is unknown

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking for `RBAR and dynamic Sql`

Also let me know if you are not able to implement same in your original requirement.

Also test this other sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table ( Value VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES ('A'),('B')

DECLARE @N INT=3
declare @i int=1
declare @c varchar(10)='C'
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(max)=''
DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(max)=''
DECLARE @CrossSql VARCHAR(max)=''
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(max)=' ORDER BY c.Value '

WHILE (@i<@N)
begin
set @Col=@Col+', c'+cast(@i as varchar)+'.Value '
SET @CrossSql=@CrossSql+' CROSS JOIN #Table c'+cast(@i as varchar)
set @OrderBy=@OrderBy+', c'+cast(@i as varchar)+'.Value '

set @i=@i+1
end
--print @ExtraSql
set @Sql='SELECT c.Value AS A'+@Col+
' FROM #Table c'
+@CrossSql
+@OrderBy

print @Sql
EXEC(@Sql)

drop table #Table
```

Answer (score 1):

This is full working example using dynamic T-SQL statement. I am holding the `K` values in temporary table. Of course, you are free to change the statement in order to fit your needs:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#KValues') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE #KValues;
END;

CREATE TABLE #KValues
(
    [value] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO #KValues ([value])
VALUES ('A')
      ,('B')
      ,('C')
      --,('D');

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) AS [ValueID]
          ,[Value]
    FROM #KValues
),
DataSourceColumns AS
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',K' + CAST([ValueID] AS VARCHAR(12)) + '.[Value]' 
            FROM DataSource
            ORDER BY [ValueID]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    ) AS [Columns]
)
SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = 'SELECT ' + (SELECT [Columns] FROM DataSourceColumns) +
' FROM #KValues AS K1' +
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ' CROSS JOIN #KValues AS K' + CAST([ValueID] AS VARCHAR(12)) 
        FROM DataSource
        ORDER BY [ValueID]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,26
    ,''
) + ' ORDER BY ' + (SELECT [Columns] FROM DataSourceColumns);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```